# Apache HttpClient cooke rejected

Tags: java, authentication, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x, shiro

We are developing a distributed system with six different deployed artifacts where each of them has their own REST API. These systems communicate via a Java client with each other over a secure SSL connection (with X509 client authentication with the help of Apache shiro).

Now at each client call to a REST resource we get the following warning (I blacked out parts of the warning with stars):

```
WARN  org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies.processCookies(ResponseProcessCookies.java:127): Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: rememberMe][value: deleteMe][domain: local.****.net][path: /abc][expiry: Fri Jan 29 11:25:07 UTC 2016]". Illegal path attribute "/abc". Path of origin: "/***/backend/abc/v1/some/other/parts/of/resource"
```

Now the problem is that we don't set any cookies in the clients and I can't figure out where and how the cookie is set (or if I can ignore the warning). I think that it correlates with the Apache Shiro configuration. The relevant cookie path of the shiro.ini looks like the following:

```
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = ***cookie
cookie.path = /
```

I hope you can help me eliminating the warning. If you need some more code examples, please let me know.

Comment: This  cookie is in the response generated by the server. Apparently the server thinks the request path is `/abc/...`, unaware that the real path (known by the client) has a prefix added.

Comment: Ok but we didn't set any cookies, I think Shiro set's this cookie and I don't know how to correct or force Shiro to set the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to override the existing cookie configuration with the one you've defined this should work:

```
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie
```

Or, if you'd like, you can turn off the cookie altogether:

```
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = false
```